# Translation of "the Table of Contents"

Tags: traduction

I'm writing an assignment in English, but I want the heading of the Table of Contents page to be in French.

I would also like to place a link at the bottom of each page saying "Return to the table of contents", but I would like that to be in French too.

What is the French translation for these English phrases?

Comment: What did you try ? How is not a dictionnary answering that ? (Table des matières, reverso gives it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Table of Contents* is “*Table des matières*” (notice the absence of a capital letter in *matières*, only the first letter of a title is made big in French). And “return to the table of contents” would be “*retour à la table des matières*” (*retour* is a noun, not a verb).